# ircmaxell password-compact under php 5.3.2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using ircmaxell password-compact library under symfony 2.4.
Before site was running on php 5.3.29 and everything was working fine. Now i moved site to new server, where php version is 5.3.2
And the problem is that now

```
password_hash($passstring, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

generates empty hash to database.

How to quickly fix this issue ? Upgrading PHP version is not an option, since this is not under my control.

Comment: [***This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7 OR a version that has the $2y fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides). Note that Debian's 5.3.3 version is NOT supported.***](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Readme for password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

> **Requirements**
>
> This library requires  PHP >= 5.3.7  OR a version that has the  $2y  fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides). Note that Debian's 5.3.3 version is NOT supported.

So unless you can backport the $2y fix, you can't use password_compat with 5.3.2

Comment: Yes, it requires 5.3.7 and greater, but as i understand, it should work with lower versions also, it just isn't secure. I'll accept that until i'll get newer php version.

Comment: run the included  version-test.php . If it outputs "Pass", you can safely use the library. If not, you cannot.

Comment: Bus as PHP 5.3 is unsupported now, and PHP 5.4 won't be supported beyond another few weeks, you really should be looking at upgrading

Comment: $2y backport did the trick. Thank you, i dont understand how i missed it before.